# Template specialization not used

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following functions defined:

```
template <typename T> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, T data);
template <> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, const char *data);
template <> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, const Glib::ustring &data);
```

When I call:

```
buffer << Glib::ustring("hello");
```

The compiler uses the general template definition instead of the specialization with `Glib::ustring`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It might be as simple as reordering your declarations.

Comment: First thing I would try is `template <> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, Glib::ustring data);`. HTH

Comment: I would recommend using classical overloads instead of full template specialization (partial specialization is another matter).  Overloads take precedence.  However, I 2nd Kerrek SB's comment above, as this example on its own does not show the problem.

Comment: @n00 - I have no idea. I know the rules are complex. These days however I've forgotten the little I knew about C++, and of course now there are two standards to refer too.

Comment: @n00 it would help if you posted something about Glib and ustring. Glib is a namespace? And ustring is a typedef? What is it a typedef for?

Comment: I removed the Glib stuff and used std::string instead [link](http://pastebin.com/GMFu3fVT).

Comment: @n00, OK I've looked it up Glib is a namespace but ustring is a regular class.

Comment: @gimpf Partial specialization is another matter mainly because partial specialization of function templates is not allowed.

Comment: `Glib::ustring("hello")` is **not** of type `const Glib::ustring &`, it's merely convertible to that type. The specialization is therefore not an exact match and there's no reason to prefer it over the generic version.

Comment: @n.m, here's a strange thing though `string x; const string& y(x); buffer << y;` and I'm still finding the generic version preferred over the `const string&` version, y looks like a exact match to me.

Comment: @n.m.: But `Glib::ustring("hello")` is an rvalue of type `Glib::ustring`, isn't it? As such it should bind to the `const&`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: it is, but the overload resolution has found a better match.

Comment: @jahhaj: `string` is not `const string&`, they are two different types, the match is not exact.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not following, in my example above y is of type `const string&`

Comment: @n.m.: You're absolutely right; I forgot that the primary template says `T data` and not `T const & data`. Cheers!

Comment: Is it feasible to change your primary template to `T const & data`?

Comment: @n.m: I totally forgot about function cs. class templates.  I'll now continue minding my own business...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a *function* template, and you want to perform *template argument deduction*. For this purpose, your function call is matched against the templated function argument `T data`. I believe that 14.8.2.4 applies to the partial ordering for your specialization where `P` is the template argument and `A` is the type of the actual argument; emphasis is mine):

> Before the partial ordering is done, certain transformations are performed on the types used for partial
>   ordering:
>
> — If `P` is a reference type, `P` is replaced by the type referred to.
>
> — **If `A` is a reference type, `A` is replaced by the type referred to.**

Thus, since the type of your argument is `A = Glib::ustring`, then this is not as good a match for the specialization `const Glib::ustring &` as the primary template is, and even if you have an actual const-reference, the reference is stripped off during the partial ordering, and you again end up with a worse match.

The usual way to fix this is to make your primary template a const-reference; this can also bind to temporary objects and should thus be "as good as" a value argument:

```
template <typename T> buffer_t & operator<<(buffer_t & buffer, T const & data);
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: How is `buffer << static_cast<Glib::ustring>("hello");` different from the code he is using `buffer << Glib::ustring("hello");
`? I'm not seeing anything in your answer that tells me why his original code didn't work.

Comment: Guessing at straws here, but can lvalue references work with temporary objects like that, or would you need an rvalue reference overload?

Comment: I rewrote the answer entirely. Please disregard previous comments.

Comment: Need fix for one of specializations in this case.
template <> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, const char * const& data);

Comment: @ForEveR: Or just an overload?! You should generally exercise restraint when dealing with function templates...

Comment: @KerrekSB or just overload of course) Using functions template specialization is bad idea in many cases...

Answer (score 7):

```
template <typename T> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, T data);
```

is primary template. Specializations are not primary templates. Compiler finds only primary templates when match functions and then, if chosen template function has specialisations looks at these, if compiler find specialization, that exactly match parameters - uses it, else uses primary template.

```
template <> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, const Glib::ustring &data)
```

this specialization not exactly matches operation `buffer_t << Glib::ustring("s")`, but this matches exactly

```
template <> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, Glib::ustring data)
```

I suggest you to not use function-template specialization, use overload.

```
template <typename T> buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, T data);
buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, const char *data);
buffer_t &operator<<(buffer_t &buffer, const Glib::ustring &data);
```